# How to convert wpf AutoCompleteBox to all uppercase input

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I have a `AutoCompleteBox` as a `DataGrid` column type. Like so:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Thing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SLToolkit:AutoCompleteBox Text="{Binding Path=Thing,
                                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

However, I want to restrict the user's input to uppercase. On `TextBoxes` I can do so like the following, but I can't get that to work with the `AutoCompleteBoxes`.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=Thing}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

I've tried this:

```
<SLToolkit:AutoCompleteBox Text="{Binding Path=Thing,
                                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           TextChanged="AutoComplete_TextChanged" />
```

With this:

```
private void AutoComplete_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     AutoCompleteBox box = sender as AutoCompleteBox;
     if (box == null) return;
     box.Text = box.Text.ToUpper();
}
```

That kind of works except that it writes backwards. When the user inputs a character, the cursor goes back to the start of the box so the next word is in front of the previous one. If I wrote 'example', I would see "ELPMAXE".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem where I only wanted entry of numbers in a textbox, so I used a behavior. If a non-number is entered, the character is deleted. I also used the interactivity library which uses the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll (just import this DLL into your project, if you don't have it its part of the blend sdk http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801).

Here is the simplified XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="Sample.SampleWindow"
            xmlns:main="clr-namespace:MySampleApp"
            xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
            Title="Sample"
            Height="800"
            Width="1025"
            >
                         <Grid>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Entry, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                     Width="30"
                                     MaxLength="4"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <main:KeyPressesWithArgsBehavior 
KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUpFilterForUpperCaseSymbols}" />
                                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </TextBox>
                         </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Uses the following Behavior class:

```
public class KeyPressesWithArgsBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    #region KeyDown Press DependencyProperty
    public ICommand KeyDownCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(KeyDownCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KeyDownCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyDownCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("KeyDownCommand", typeof (ICommand), typeof (KeyPressesWithArgsBehavior));

    #endregion KeyDown Press DependencyProperty

    #region KeyUp Press DependencyProperty

    public ICommand KeyUpCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(KeyUpCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KeyUpCommandProperty, value);}
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyUpCommandProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("KeyUpCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof (KeyPressesWithArgsBehavior));

    #endregion KeyUp Press DependencyProperty

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(AssociatedUIElementKeyDown);
        AssociatedObject.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(AssociatedUIElementKeyUp);
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(AssociatedUIElementKeyDown);
        AssociatedObject.KeyUp -= new KeyEventHandler(AssociatedUIElementKeyUp);
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void AssociatedUIElementKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (KeyDownCommand != null)
        {
            ObjectAndArgs oa = new ObjectAndArgs {Args = e, Object = AssociatedObject};
            KeyDownCommand.Execute(oa);
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedUIElementKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (KeyUpCommand != null)
        {
            KeyUpCommand.Execute(AssociatedObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your View Model you can implement the command.
SampleWindowViewModel.cs:

```
    public ICommand KeyUpFilterForUpperCaseSymbolsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_keyUpFilterForUpperCaseSymbolsCommand== null)
            {
                _keyUpFilterForUpperCaseSymbolsCommand= new RelayCommand(KeyUpFilterForUpperCaseSymbols);
            }
            return _keyUpFilterForUpperCaseSymbolsCommand;
        }
    }
```

...

```
    private void KeyUpFilterForUpperCaseSymbols(object sender)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb is TextBox)
        {
            // check for a lowercase character here
            // then modify tb.Text, to exclude that character.
            // Example: tb.Text = oldText.Substring(0, x);
        }
    }
```